# Which data structure to use in Python to store data like this?

Tags: python

I want to store data[year][month] = day

Where year and month can both be keys of a dict.

An operation like data[year][month].append(day) could be possible.

Comment: So use a dictionary...

Comment: Use a nested dictionary then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested dictionaries:

```
data[year] = {}
data[year][month] = [day]
```

To make this a little easier, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)

data[year][month] = [day]
```

or even:

```
def monthdict():
    return defaultdict(list)
data = defaultdict(monthdict)

data[year][month].append(day)
```

Demo of the latter structure:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def monthdict():
...     return defaultdict(list)
... 
>>> data = defaultdict(monthdict)
>>> data[2013][3].append(23)
>>> data
defaultdict(<function monthdict at 0x10c9d0500>, {2013: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {3: [23]})})
```

Comment: I was using data = defaultdict(list) and hence caused myself a heck load of confusion.

Comment: To continue this a bit more if I may, to reach to the traverse to the innermost element in a double dict-list (Or is it called something else?) is Theta(n^3) right? Is there a lesser time complex method to go about storing data like this? Does Python offer a better data structure?

Comment: @Hick: No, the `dict` access is only O(1). If you search through the list then that is O(n) for a list length n. A traverse to the day lists is entirely done in constant time.

Comment: Oh! I sort of ended up treating Double dict-list as a 3D array in C. My bad.

Comment: If its not too late, how exactly is this O(n)? What I am doing: http://pastebin.com/x3iZsnvQ

Comment: @Hick: What you do is O(nm); n years and m months. Months is quite limited (there are only ever 12 in a year). Yes, you are scanning through all the keys of the dictionaries; I was talking about scanning through the inner *list* for one year + month key combo.

Comment: @Hick: If all you do is scan through all years and all months all the time, then you need to rethink your data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a dict-of-dicts-of-lists?

```
data = {'1972' :  {
                   '01': ['a', 'list', 'of', 'things'],
                   '02': ['another', 'list', 'of', 'things'],
                  },
        '1973' :  {
                   '01': ['yet', 'another', 'list', 'of', 'things'],
                  },
        }        

>>> data['1972']['02']
['another', 'list', 'of', 'things']

>>> data['1972']['01'].append(42)
>>> data
{'1972': {'01': ['a', 'list', 'of', 'things', 42],
  '02': ['another', 'list', 'of', 'things']},
 '1973': {'01': ['yet', 'another', 'list', 'of', 'things']}}
```